# Is the argument below valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have just started to learn Logic and want to understand is the following argument valid and how to formalize it in First-Order Logic:

```
Plato is Human
Plato has 5 fingers on his left hand
Plato has 5 fingers on his right hand

Socrates is Human
Socrates has 4 fingers on his left hand
Socrates has 4 fingers on his right hand
——
All humans have the same number of fingers on both hands
```

And then:

```
All humans have the same number of fingers on both hands
Aristotle is Human
Aristotle has 3 fingers on his left hand
——
Aristotle has 3 fingers on his right hand
```

Can I use Universal generalization to prove Argument 1?

Comment: First one: obviously not. Maybe Aristotle has 5 fingers on the right and 3 on the left.

Comment: The second one is: obviously the premise is False and thus also the conclusion may be False.

Comment: First one: can I use Universal Generalization and state 'All humans have ...' as Hypothesis? Following: https://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/logic/pred_logic/inference/univ_gen.html

Comment: You cannot "generalize" on two humans... there are many more.

Comment: The conclusion is plainly False; thus, something has gone wrong...

Comment: I see. Is there a logic system where I can reason/generalize from examples?

Comment: That is [Induction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/), and it is well-known that can lead only to "reasonable" conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is false because you can't prove the statement using given results. Just because it is true for those 2 people does not make it true for everyone.

The second one is true, because we are given the statement so you can get the results from it. In this case, because it is given that all humans have the same number of fingers on both sides, and Aristotle is human, he will have the same amount of fingers on both, which is 3.

Edit: I am assuming that the cases are separate. If they are not, then the second one would be false because the given statement was from the first one is false.